# compile aosp 32 bit linux

Tags: c++, gcc

looking to compile 4.4.2 aosp source following the guide https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-building/xFtX6K42BDE. why is host not compiling properly?

```
Install: /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/bin/acp
host StaticLib: libbz (/home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/libbz.a)
prebuilts/tools/gcc-sdk/ar crsP  /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/libbz.a /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/blocksort.o /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/huffman.o /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/crctable.o /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/randtable.o /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/compress.o /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/decompress.o /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/STATIC_LIBRARIES/libbz_intermediates/bzlib.o
cp -fp /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp /home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/bin/acp
cp: cannot stat `/home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/obj/EXECUTABLES/acp_intermediates/acp': No such file or directory
make: *** [/home/brandonabandon/sn/out/host/linux-x86/bin/acp] Error 1
=make -j4 otapackage showcommands.
```

so earlier, `cp cannot stat: /brandonabandon/host/blah/blah_intermediates blah.d: no such file or directory` is occuring many times. i compiled 32 bit arm toolchains for building android with gcc 4.8, and kernel compilation with 4.9. my assumption is the host toolchain needs pointed accurately. if so, i dont know how to do it. any help?

Comment: i did include the host path located at gcc-sdk. previously undefined after editing (incorrectly) for 32 bit compilation

Comment: Hi, I reverted the change to add {SOLVED}. We don't do that here - instead, you should add the solution as an answer - you can even accept your own answer if you so wish

Answer (score 0):

gcc=

```
#!/bin/bash

*PROGNAME=`basename $0`

PREFIX32=../../gcc/linux-x86/host/i686-linux-glibc2.7-4.6/bin/i686-linux
options=" ${@} "
# sentinel prefix/suffix space to simplify pattern match below
suffix_m32=${options##* -m32 } # suffix after the last -m32
len_m32=${#suffix_m32} # length of suffix after the last -m32
# Always choose 32-bit
MY_TOOL=`dirname $0`/${PREFIX32}-${PROGNAME}

*$MY_TOOL "$@"
```

i did a star before the required changes